# pivot/unpivot statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

Hi, having table like this

```
NR PROJECT  RESULT
1  name1    234
1  name2    937
2  name1    3
2  name2    6
```

I'm trying to have results presented this way:

```
NR NAME1 NAME2
1  234   937
2  3     6
```

so the VALUES of the PROJECT column become headers presenting respective RES value while the same NR values are merged into a single row

help :)

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of `projects` that you want to do this for?  SQL is for Structured data, where the number of fields (and their names) won't change.  If your list of projects will vary at all, it will mean your desired number of columns will vary too, that's a really bad place to be and an SQL-Anti-Pattern.  The recommended design pattern for such a case is normalisation; the structure you're starting with.  If you're doing this for presentation to a user, that's a SQL-Anti-Pattern to, presentation formatting should not generally be done in SQL.  In short: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: maybe I simplified my question too much to present the problem. Presented "table" is just a set of rows which we're starting with, don't need to go into details here. Changing the source is not an option here

Comment: Then you need to answer the question of Why you want to do this. In 99.9% of cases you should Not do it.  There are nearly always alternatives, and they are nearly always preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a fixed list of projects, you can use (as you've mention in the title of your question) a `pivot`.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    yourTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(result)
    FOR project IN ('name1' AS NAME1, 'name2' AS NAME2)
)
```

This would give the same results as from a "conditional aggregate".

```
SELECT
    NR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PROJECT = 'name1' THEN result END)   AS NAME1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PROJECT = 'name2' THEN result END)   AS NAME2
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    NR
```

Examples : http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19f31ce152f4f88c3d74e867016765d7

Comment: sadly, the project names have to be fetched somehow